# C and gcc error array subscript is above array bounds

Tags: c

I have a to deal with a structure of a lib :

```
typedef struct {
   uint8_t   response_type;
   uint8_t   error_code;
   uint16_t sequence;
   uint32_t resource_id;
   uint16_t minor_code;
   uint8_t major_code;
   uint8_t pad0;
   uint32_t pad[5];
   uint32_t full_sequence;
} a_structure;
```

my problem come from the pad[5] member of the structure that I don't really understand.
I thougth this member can be used as the other member in function like that:

```
uint8_t get_response_type( a_structure * my_struct)
{
   return my_struct->response_type;
}
```

but this function:

```
uint32_t get_pad_5( a_structure * my_struct)
{
   return my_struct->pad[5];
}
```

generate warning in gcc

> error array subscript is above array bounds

Can someone explain me what this means ?

Thxs

Comment: I had a fairly convolution code that gcc managed to figure out and warned "error array subscript is above array bounds.  So even though this post problem was obvious, finding this (because of the posted matching warning) did help solve my more complex issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Structure field `pad` was defined as "array of 5 `uint32_t`". You must differ variable definition from using the variable. So since `pad` is defined, `pad[5]` means "get the fifth (counting from 0) element of `pad` array". But there is no such element in `pad` array, because the highest index available for this array is 4.

Also, it seems that you want to return pointer to the first element of this array, not the fifth element. So you must rewrite your function this way:

```
uint32_t * get_pad_5( a_structure * my_struct)
{
    return my_struct->pad;
}
```

Comment: From what do you conclude the OP is interested i the 1st element?

Comment: @alk OP wants to deal with "pad[5] member". That is he doesn't understand either array indexing (there is no fifth element in `pad` array) or array/pointer definition/using (member of structure is `pad`, not `pad[5]`). And also I believe that the second problem makes much more confusion for a newbie.

Comment: Technically `pad[5]` is the _sixth_ element if the index is 0-based. There's no sixth element, hence the error. If you are looking for the last element in an array in a generic manner, try `pad[sizeof(pad)-1]`. It's resolved at compile time so there's no speed penalty, and any future changes to the array won't cripple related code.

Answer (score 5):

When you crate an array with 5 members, they get indexed 0-4, if you try to acces 5, you're out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C are zero based.

```
my_struct->pad[0]; // the first pad
my_struct->pad[4]; // the fifth pad
```

The warning means that you are trying to access an element outside the array. An index of `5` means the sixths element and the array only has 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 5 elements has indices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. The index `5` is out of bounds. In general an array of N elements has valid indices from `0` to `N-1` inclusive.